# PHP: Multidimensional array into function call

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to build a simple URL router that loads predefined urls and settings into an array. Then I need to push it all to a function with a static variable so I can store all the urls and settings in a uniform way.

The array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [index] => Array
        (
            [#title] => Home
            [#access] => user_access
            [#callback] => page_index
        )

    [admin/dashboard] => Array
        (
            [#title] => Dashboard
            [#access_callback] => user_access
            [#page_callback] => page_dashboard
        )

    [admin/stats]
```

Then I want to push the data from the array into a function:

```
route('path/path', #callback, #title, #access);
```

I am trying to build the foreach loops but I can't get passed this mess:

```
foreach($routes as $path => $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    }
 route($path, );
}
```

I feel like I am approaching this the wrong way. Any help would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want to do is just break it down to that first array. So:

```
foreach ( $routes as $path => $array ) {

    route ( $path, $array );

}
```

Then within `route`, you would work with the array by just referring to the title, access and callback keys. Like `$array['title']` to do something with the title. Just my take on it.